# Make a localhost instance in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My friend will share to me a huge C# source code.. and all of the 54 projects there uses a connection string in their nhibernate config like this:

Server=localhost;Database=asd_db;Integrated Security=false;user id=XXX;password=XXXXX;Application Name=ASD 1.2 WebApp;

I have a new laptop and I will install SQL Server 2008 R2, I'm kinda confused with the way it does its installation...

What should I do, during the installation, to make a server that is named `LOCALHOST` in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  That'll take care of itself.

Comment: so what should i put if it asks me the name of an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just install SQL Server as a "default instance", and create the login accounts and you should be fine. Localhost will just use the ip address in your hosts file (127.0.0.1) to connect to the SQL Server instance on the default port.

Comment: it will not ask me for named instances?

Comment: When installing SQL Server, I believe you can choose either a default instance, or create a named instance. Since your connection string looks like it does not specify a named instance, I think you should use the default instance.